# What are the Cypher commands to delete index and index entry

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I use the default Lucene index engine, what is the Cypher command to delete an index? and  what is the Cypher command to delete an index entry within a specific index?

Answer (score 7):

I do not know if your question is out of date because you know use a newer version of Neo4j but in version 2.2.1 there is the possibility to drop an index using `Cypher` via

```
DROP INDEX ON :Label(property)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if there's a way to delete an `Index` using `Cypher`..

But you can do it using `Neo4j API` as follows:

```
for ( String indexName : server.getDatabase().graph.index()
                    .nodeIndexNames() )
            {
                    try{
                        server.getDatabase().graph.index()
                                .forNodes( indexName )
                                .delete();
                    } catch(UnsupportedOperationException e) {
                            // Encountered a read-only index.
                    }
            }

            for ( String indexName : server.getDatabase().graph.index()
                    .relationshipIndexNames() )
            {
                    try {
                        server.getDatabase().graph.index()
                                .forRelationships( indexName )
                                .delete();
                    } catch(UnsupportedOperationException e) {
                            // Encountered a read-only index.
                    }
            }
```

You can have a look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/nzMjtkwYCFM), it may help you..

Comment: Hi ManSour, Thanks for the answer. I found that the Cypher command to delete an index is: index --delete "index_name". But still do not know the Cypher command to delete an index entry within a specific index.