# How to delete all indexes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I want to delete all indexes that exist using cypher in a bulk can it be done? I am using neo4j 3.4.7.

```
DROP INDEX  ON :Label(attributename)
```

Does it replace existing indexes if I create the same index in a later stage?

Comment: The solutions at [StackOverflow: Neo4j how to drop all constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357379/neo4j-how-to-drop-all-constraints) and the last solution [StackOverflow: delete multiple indexes via java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516809/what-are-the-cypher-commands-to-delete-index-and-index-entry) may help you.

Comment: If you (re) create an identical index, you get no error and the existing one will not be touched. See [StackOverflow: create index on when the index already exists in Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408327/launching-a-create-index-on-when-the-index-already-exists-in-neo4j).

Answer (score 14):

A quick way to drop all indexes and constraints is to use the APOC procedure [apoc.schema.assert](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_schema), as follows:

```
CALL apoc.schema.assert({},{},true) YIELD label, key
RETURN *
```

The procedure is mainly for ensuring that the DB has the indexes and constraints passed in the first 2 maps, but the third parameter determines whether any other indexes and constraints are dropped. In the above query, the first 2 maps are empty, so the end result is that all indexes and constraints are dropped.

Comment: Note that this doesn't apply to compound indexes or node key constraints, and I don't believe it applies to property existence constraints either.

Comment: Can I check if an index exists in cypher ?  @cybersam

Comment: The Cypher language itself has no way to check for index existence. But the APOC plugin has several [procedures for getting index/constraint info](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_schema_information). In particular, `apoc.schema.node.indexExists()` will tell you if a specific index exists.

Comment: The existence of an index can be checked with this: one row is returned if a property index exists else zero rows are returned.
`
    CALL db.indexes() YIELD description
    WHERE description = "INDEX ON :Publication(source_id)"
    RETURN *;
`

Comment: Cypher has had [SHOW INDEXES](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/#indexes-list-indexes) for awhile now.

Answer (score 6):

For release 3.x your can to use built-in procedures Neo4j to delate  what index your want.   From web browser your can send Cipher  query:

`CALL db.indexes()`    - List all indexes in the database.

`CALL  db.index.fulltext.drop()`   -Drop the specified index.

or
  `CALL db.index.explicit.drop()`   - Remove an explicit index - YIELD type,name,config

All possible built-in procedures and parameter for last version     [here User management for Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/procedures/)

old style  do it  with CIPHER :

DROP INDEX ON :labelOfNode(propertyOfNode)

CREATE INDEX ON :labelOfNode(propertyOfNode)

Comment: A note: these drop procedures are available in Enterprise Edition only.